# Couldn't get the reason for the fault in the code

Tags: c

This is a program to print the smallest value and its position in an array (defined by user).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int position_smallest(int a[],int n)
{
    int smallest = a[0];
    int i,k;
    for(i=0; i<=n-1; i=i+1)
    {
        if(a[i]<a[0])
        {
            smallest = a[i];
            k = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The smallest value is %d\n", smallest);
    printf("It's position is %d\n", k); 
    return 0;
 }

int main()
{
    int n,j;
    int a[n];
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(j=0; j<=n; j=j+1)
    {
         printf("a[%d] = ", j);
         scanf("%d", &a[j]);
    }
    position_smallest(a,n); 
}
```

But upon running it, it shows following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What can be the possible reason(s) for it?

Comment: For a start you create an array of size n but n is uninitialised at the time.

Comment: You can't go from 0 to `n` inclusive but exclusive so try `j < n`. Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: First of all, Your array `a`'s size is `n` and `n` has no value until u get input.

Comment: And that's why my compiler can't compile it when there array `a`'s size is n.

Answer (score 1):

First error, as stated in one of the comments, is declaring an array of size n before even knowing how much n is.

Second mistake is for loop in your main function that goes from 0 to n, i.e. index of an array is out of bounds.

Try this:

```
int main() {
    int n = 0, j = 0;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[n];

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("a[%d] = ", j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[j]);
    }
    position_smallest(a,n);
}
```

If this solved your problem, please mark it.

Comment: The second error does not exist. The OP's condition i <=n-1 is equivalent to your i<n. EDIT: whoops,  I was looking at the testing loop, while the error is in the filling loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
int n, j;
```

both uninitialized. Initialize them otherwise you will get garbage values.

```
int n = 0, j = 0;
```

What happens if `n` by chance (very likely) is `0` in following line?

```
int a[n];
```

You allocate `0` bytes for array `a[]`. You then enter `10` in following line

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

You will get `segmentation fault` in `for()` loop below because your loop is trying to put `10` elements where you allocated no memory at all.

What happens if uninitialized `n` by chance (very likely) is 2^32 * 4 bytes (`int`s max)?

```
int a[n];
```

You allocate 2^32 bytes for array `a[]`. You then enter `10` in following line

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

You will not get `segmentation fault` but you will allocate 2^32 * 4 bytes of memory for your program and you will use only 10

Second if that is not enough:

```
for (j = 0; j <= n; ++j)
    scanf("%d", arr[n];
```

will access `11th` element of array which is undefined behavior, and you might even get `segmentation fault` there. As you know arrays in `C` arrays are indexed from `0` to `n - 1` (if `n` is size of array).

Third your loop inside function:

```
for(i=0; i<=n-1; i=i+1)
```

is the same as:

```
for(i=0; i < n; ++i)
```

And finally, you have a bug in your code, I believe:

```
if(a[i]<a[0])
```

should be:

```
if (a[i] < smallest)
```

because it is most likely that you would like compare other number to already smallest element not to `a[0]`. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int position_smallest(int a[],int n) {
    int smallest = a[0];
    int i = 0, k=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        if(a[i]<smallest) {
            smallest = a[i];
            k = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The smallest value is %d\n", smallest);
    printf("It's position is %d\n", k);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int n=0, j=0;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    int a[n];

    for(j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        printf("a[%d] = ", j);
        scanf("%d", &a[j]);
    }
    position_smallest(a,n);

    return 0;
}
```

The version above is legit for `C99` and up standards. If you are using `C89` and earlier compilers you are stack with fixed size as mentioned in @Saurabh's answer or preferably use `malloc()`.

Here is `malloc()` version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int position_smallest(int a[],int n) {
    int smallest = a[0];
    int i=0,k=0;
    for(i=0; i<=n-1; i=i+1) {
        if(a[i]<smallest) {
            smallest = a[i];
            k = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The smallest value is %d\n", smallest);
    printf("It's position is %d\n", k);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int n=0, j=0;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    for(j=0; j<n; j=j+1) {
        printf("a[%d] = ", j);
        scanf("%d", &a[j]);                                                                                                                                                              
    }
    position_smallest(a,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gox for giving knowledge to me about a new function `malloc()`. I didn't knew it before your answer. 

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int position_smallest(int a[],int n)
{
    int smallest = a[0];
    int i,k;
    for(i=0; i<=n-1; i=i+1)
    {
        if(a[i]<a[0])
        {
            smallest = a[i];
            k = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The smallest value is %d\n", smallest);
    printf("It's position is %d\n", k); 
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n,j;
    int a[100];
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(j=0; j<n; j=j+1)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ", j);
        scanf("%d", &a[j]);
    }
    position_smallest(a,n); 
}
```

Specify the size of the array anything but run the loop according to user's input.

And there is some problems in your function `position_smallest`. So if you want correct it then take a look at @Gox's answer.